# O javascript não esta funcionando no django

Tags: javascript, python, django

ja tentei de todas as formas, mas não consigo fazer o JS funcionar.

login.js:

```
$('.message a').click(function(){
   $('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
});
```

login.html;

```
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'gestao_clientes/css/login.css' %}" media="screen" />
    <script src='{% static "gestao_clientes/js/login.js" %}'></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="login-page">
      <div class="form">
        <form class="register-form">
          <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
          <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
          <input type="text" placeholder="email address"/>
          <button>create</button>
          <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="#">Sign In</a></p>
        </form>
        <form class="login-form">
          <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
          <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
          <button>login</button>
          <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a></p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Já tentei:
- com e sem o **type="text/javascript"**

- também: **src="gestao_clientes/js/login.js"**

Meu diretório está da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A parte de settings do meu projeto está assim:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'rwn)otj+b3_nt6u(0rw^n9bw^yhd-0!h!3xtx$bwsa1%7hdv(q'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'clientes',
    'login',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'gestao_clientes.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'gestao_clientes.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS =[
    'estaticos',
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = 'media'

LOGIN_URL = ''

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'person_list'
```

A pagina de login e cadastro será a primeria pagina do projeto, 
e gostaria que ficasse de acordo com essa: https://codepen.io/colorlib/pen/rxddKy

Porém quando clico em *create an account" não abre para inserir os outros dados. 
Obrigado pela ajuda, sou iniciante nessa parte :)

Comment: Não vejo onde estás a carregar o jQuery...

Comment: é necessário? Ainda não sei sobre j'Query

Comment: Estás a utilizar jQuery, tens de importar no teu login.html;

Comment: Descarrega jQuery e coloca numa pasta na tua app, e adicionas a linha <script src="{% static 'main/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>

Comment: Ok, vou tentar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicando melhor, descarregas o jQuery e colocas na pasta de templates na tua app e colocas assim.

**login.html**

```
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'gestao_clientes/css/login.css' %}" media="screen" />

    <script src="{% static 'gestao_clientes/login/templates/jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js' %}"></script>

    <script src='{% static "gestao_clientes/js/login.js" %}'></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="login-page">
      <div class="form">
        <form class="register-form">
          <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
          <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
          <input type="text" placeholder="email address"/>
          <button>create</button>
          <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="#">Sign In</a></p>
        </form>
        <form class="login-form">
          <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
          <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
          <button>login</button>
          <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a></p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**login.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.message a').click(function(){
     $('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
  });
});
```

Comment: Fiz isso mas não deu certo, continuou a mesma coisa

Comment: Atenção que tens de colocar o caminho correto para o teu ficheiro, eu coloquei main/vendor/jquery/...file, tens colocar para o teu caso e para a tua diretoria correta, eu testei seu código com jQuery e funcionou.

Comment: No seu teste o **Create an account** funcionou normal?
Já mudei o diretório mas mesmo assim não está funcionando

Comment: Partilha no github seu projeto e eu analiso

Comment: Já editei o código de forma que funciona, só estou procurando perceber o que tens mal ao importar o teu login.js ou o que está errado que este não funciona.

Comment: Agora sim, podes tcorrigir o teu código do login.js, faltava $(document).ready(function().

Comment: Muito obrigado!! Agradeço demais!! :)))